Unknown type name '__time64_t'
Trying compile my project with gcc is success. When trying to do so with any clang-based compiler the following error occur:
[build] /usr/bin/clang++ -I/mnt/40ab93ed-5db8-4e22-a055-9775c3e5b937/ISC-parser/include -I/mnt/40ab93ed-5db8-4e22-a055-9775c3e5b937/ISC-parser/stdlibs -I/media/ura/Data/include -g -std=c++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/parser.dir/src/CLL/function/function.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/parser.dir/src/CLL/function/function.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/parser.dir/src/CLL/function/function.cpp.o -c /mnt/40ab93ed-5db8-4e22-a055-9775c3e5b937/ISC-parser/src/CLL/function/function.cpp
[build] In file included from /mnt/40ab93ed-5db8-4e22-a055-9775c3e5b937/ISC-parser/src/CLL/function/function.cpp:4:
[build] In file included from /mnt/40ab93ed-5db8-4e22-a055-9775c3e5b937/ISC-parser/include/parser.h:8:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/iostream:41:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/ostream:40:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/ios:44:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/bits/ios_base.h:39:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/ext/atomicity.h:35:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/14/bits/gthr.h:157:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/14/bits/gthr-default.h:35:
[build] In file included from /include/pthread.h:22:
[build] In file included from /include/sched.h:31:
[build] /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/time_t.h:8:9: error: unknown type name '__time64_t'
[build]     8 | typedef __time64_t time_t;
[build]       |         ^
[build] In file included from /mnt/40ab93ed-5db8-4e22-a055-9775c3e5b937/ISC-parser/src/CLL/function/function.cpp:4:
[build] In file included from /mnt/40ab93ed-5db8-4e22-a055-9775c3e5b937/ISC-parser/include/parser.h:8:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/iostream:41:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/ostream:40:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/ios:44:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/bits/ios_base.h:39:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/ext/atomicity.h:35:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/14/bits/gthr.h:157:
[build] In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/14/bits/gthr-default.h:35:
[build] In file included from /include/pthread.h:22:
[build] In file included from /include/sched.h:32:
[build] /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_timespec.h:14:3: error: unknown type name '__time64_t'
[build]    14 |   __time64_t tv_sec;            /* Seconds.  */
[build]       |   ^

I think that may be an incorrect installation of compiler though I tried to reinstall gcc and it's libraries, add definitions -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_TIME_BITS=64 not helped

In my distro it's defined in types.h.

Helped to add explicitly definition __LIBC

This seems to come from the last block of posix/bits/types.h? You could try: #define __time64_t time_t? It's what time/mktime-internal.h does for 32 bit non-libc.

@Craig Estey the definition not helped, but the typedef long long __time64_t also made the compilation successful. I looked the bits/types.h header mentioned above and found there the definition occur when also __LIBC macro defined. I consider such definition to be more optimal.
